# angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am very much new to angularjs, i have look many webpages but not get any concrete solutions.

What i am trying to achieve is i am creating one factory service to authenticate the user. After successful authentication it navigate to dashboard page.

i am getting the following error:

```
angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Object.factory.authentication (login.html:74)
    at r.$scope.loginCall (login.html:65)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:218)
    at e (angular.js:23613)
    at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16152)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

My Html Code is :

```
    <div ng-app="loginFormApp" ng-controller="loginFormCtrl">

<form method="post" action="" id="login_form" class="row">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Login ID" ng-model="loginId" >
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" >
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-theme" ng-click="loginCall()" value="Login">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-theme" ng-click="loginCall()" value="Register Here">
                        </form>
                        </div>
```

my controller is :

```
 var app = angular.module('loginFormApp', []);
            app.controller('loginFormCtrl', function($scope, $http, AuthService) {
                $scope.loginCall = function() {

                    AuthService.authentication();

                };
            });
```

My Factory Service is :

```
 app.factory('AuthService', function() {
            var factory = {};
            factory.authentication = function($http) {
                //alert("hello1");
                $http.post("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/authenticate", {
                        'userName': $scope.loginId,
                        'password': $scope.password
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {

                        window.location.href = "http://103.19.89.152:8080/earnfit/ui/angular/dashboard.html";
                    });
            };
            return factory;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Factory method, you are not injecting $http and hence its undefined when you access it.

Please refer the below code

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
return {
    authentication : function (UserName, Password) {
        $http.post("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/authenticate", { 'userName': UserName, 'password': Password})
            .then(function (response) { window.location.href = "http://103.19.89.152:8080/earnfit/ui/angular/dashboard.html";}, 
                  // Error Handling
                  function (response) {console.log(response)});
    }
  }
});
```

So, if you observe I removed the scope and instead I am passing the login data as parameters which will work as injecting $scope is not recommended.

-- Farhan

Comment: So did the above comment help you resolve the issue?

Comment: Yeah it's work for me Thanks Syed Farhan Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$http` 
as dependency on line in factory.

```
app.factory('AuthService', function($http) {
```

Regards.

Comment: hva narola : i added $http as dependency on line in factory but it is giving angular.js:12520Error: [$injector:unpr]  error.